# ENV caching issue on local development (PHP-FPM, NGINX & LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

We are running a laravel application by docker. We are creating a docker container using PHP-FPM (**php:7.0-fpm official image**) & NGINX. We use a common **.env** file for both docker and laravel applications.

> we up & running our application by - `docker-compose --env-file=./.env -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

But the problem is when we change our **.env** file, the application not detected the change. We want to get every .env file change without **re-creating** the **container**.

### Dockerfile -

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm

# PHP_CPPFLAGS are used by the docker-php-ext-* scripts
ENV PHP_CPPFLAGS="$PHP_CPPFLAGS -std=c++11"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libvpx-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    git

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql mbstring zip calendar soap gd intl

# Install mongodb extension
RUN pecl install mongodb-1.4.4 \
    && echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.8.6
RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo

COPY entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /etc/entrypoint.sh

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 80 443
```

### Docker Compose -

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  api-service:
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${API_DOMAIN}
    working_dir: /var/www
    entrypoint: /etc/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ../../:/var/www
      - ../nginx/conf.d/nginx-local.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
      - ../php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - ../php/memory_limit.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory_limit.ini
      - ../php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.override.ini
      - ../php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:80

networks:
  api-service-network:
    external:
      name: ${EXTERNAL_NETWORK}
```

### entrypoint -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
service nginx start
php-fpm
```

So is it possible to reload **ENV** (***on local development by PHP-FPM***) without recreating the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `env_file` in docker-compose

[Maybe can help you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

Comment: I think it is doing the same thing - 
docker-compose `--env-file=./.env` -f docker-compose.yml up -d

Comment: Maybe its better pass the .env via `volumes` (for laravel) cause volumes has bind